# R : round p values to two significant digits in xtable and ReporteRs export to Latex/Office/LibreOffice

Tags: r, export, xtable, significant-digits, reporters

I am using a combination of `xtable`, `rtable` and `ReporteRs` to export summary tables of various objects (`aov`, `glm`'s, `lm`'s etc) to Latex/Word/Powerpoint. I'm not so fond of the default way, however, in which p values are given with a fixed number of digits after the comma. Instead I would prefer that it would give me p values in a similar format as one would get with base R function `format.pval()` with `digits=2`, i.e. give p values rounded to two significant digits - in this case 4.2e-17 and 0.25).

E.g.

```
ctl = c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt = c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group = gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight = c(ctl, trt)
fit = lm(weight ~ group)
s=summary(fit)
s

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   4.8465     0.1557  31.124   <2e-16 ***
group1        0.1855     0.1557   1.191    0.249    

library(xtable)
library(rtable)
library(ReporteRs)
tab=as.FlexTable(xtable(s))
tab
```

[image]

I would like to have the p-values formatted in a similar way as in `summary(fit)`, however (right aligned, rounded to two significant digits, in this case 4.2e-17 and 0.25).
Anybody any idea how this could be achieved in a generic way, ideally for the p values given by all the objects supported by `xtable`?

EDIT: with the help below I now made a [[small package `export`]](https://github.com/tomwenseleers/export) with helper functions `table2doc`, `table2ppt` and `table2html` to export the previously shown R stats object to Word, Powerpoint or HTML (and with function `graph2ppt` and `graph2doc` to export the currently active graph to Powerpoint or Word), see
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/export/index.html and
https://github.com/tomwenseleers/export

Comment: what about `xtable(s, digits = c(4,4,4,2,2), display = c('f','f','f','f','g'))`

Comment: Thx for that - this goes some way towards solving the problem, although the next problem would then be to redefine these default params for all the objects that xtable can deal with (not all of them have a p value column, and they have different nrs of columns). What would be the most elegant way to do this?

Comment: (this would be part of two functions I am writing table2doc and table2ppt to export R objects to tables in word or powerpoint, and so it is important it adequately deals with all possible xtable input objects)

Comment: you might write small functions to return the type of display and digits based on the column names of the fit object, a look-up table in essence. such as `get_display <- function(x) {key <- setNames(c('f','f','f','g'), c('Estimate','Std. Error','t value','Pr')); key[sapply(x, function(xx) grep(xx, names(key)))]}
get_display(colnames(s$coefficients))` and I would use it like `get_display(colnames(s$coefficients))` which gives me the f,f,f,g above. And you can use a similar approach for setting the digits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a helper function that will look for a signature of a p-value, which I am taking to be those colnames that have "Pr" in them:

```
xtable2 <- function(x, ...) {  sm <- x[['coefficients']]; ncol <- ncol(sm)
                             whch<- grep("Pr", colnames(sm))
                             digs <- rep(4, ncol+1); digs[whch+1] <- 2
                             disp <-rep("f", ncol+1); disp[whch+1] <- "g"
                  xtable(x, digits= digs, display=disp, ...) }

> tab <- as.FlexTable(xtable2(s)); tab
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly for the `lm` example, but for `aov` I get `fit = aov(weight ~ group); s=summary(fit); as.FlexTable(xtable2(s))`  `Error in rep(4, ncol + 1) : invalid 'times' argument` - `x[['coefficients']]` there doesn't work - any thoughts how to fix that?

Comment: Ha with `asdf=function(x) {
    if(length(x) == 1) {
      as.data.frame(x[[1]])
    } else {
      lapply(unlist(x, FALSE), as.data.frame)
    }
  }; sm = asdf(s)` it works

Comment: Ha or even better `sm=xtable(x)`also works and is more generic, working for any supported class of x!

Comment: The problem with aov is that it returns a list of objects that need to be process separate, which it appears you sorted out. `lm` and `glm` return a single list with `coefficient` leaves.

Comment: Thx again for your help and the clarification! Wrapped my functions to export stats objects (or R graphs) to MS Office in a small R package now at https://github.com/tomwenseleers/export2office